# Message Queuing on python 2.2

Tags: python, message-queue, python-2.2

How to do a Message Queuing in **python 2.2**?
Must be in python 2.2, I need for a legacy system.

I've already looked a lot and found nothing, I'm already thinking that it can not be done.
Which I do not doubt, since python 2.2 is quite old.

Comment: You could maybe use something like Redis, but you'd probably have to write your own client for it since the chances of any of the existing Redis client libraries working with a version of Python that old are so low it's probably not worth looking.

Comment: Have you considered upgrade to python 2.7? It should be backward compatible with all the code you have therefore won't take too much effort.

Comment: We are upgrading, but I need to make it work on 2.2.

Comment: @MatthewDaly I need to consume a queuing on Amazon sqs

Comment: @HebertSouza I think the way to go will probably be to roll your own API client to work with SQS as it's unlikely you can find an existing working integration

Answer (score 0):

I made a .jar that reads the queue and inserts in our database. And a listener in python that looks at the table.
Not python 2.2, but work's.